# Incorporate an image as part of text

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, swift2, nsstring

Is there anyway to create text/font with an image and use it as part of a string? I would like to display our coin image before the amount in labels, etc in various places in my app. So, for instance, instead of $4.00, it would be my custom currency image instead of the $ sign.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to convert our currency image into some sort of a font text (like what font awesome does) and use it in strings.

If not what would be a good way to approach this, so that we can display currency amounts all over our app with our own custom currency image? Some sort of a custom label?

Comment: A Font is technically a glyph sheet and associated data stored in tables to help with offsets, sizes, etc. I guess you *could* create a "font" that basically has a single character and is resizable, but that seems like a lot of effort. A better way may be to create an emoji. (Maybe. I don't know enough about that.) If so, it's a Unicode character you can use as text. The easiest option is to subclass UILabel, add to the *draw(rect:)* method what is needed to display your image, and then add it into your UI. Yes, you may have some "leading" space between it and the amount, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `NSAttributeString` to accomplish this with an `NSTextAttachment`

```
let dollarImage = UIImage(named: "DollarSign")

let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = dollarImage
attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: dollarImage.size)

let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
let currencyString = NSAttributedString(string: "4.40")

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attachmentString)
attributedString.append(currencyString)
```

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, but how could I ensure that the image height aligns nicely with the text height?

Comment: The best way to design your image to match the text you're expecting. Include whitespace in the image if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, not following...how do you include whitespace in the image?

Comment: Maybe your icon is 10x5 pixels. So you save it with padding around the icon to make the image 14x10 pixels so it has built in whitespace around the icon.